# Load image/link in UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Attempting to load an html file into webview that has images that link to other pages in the supporting files folder.  The main html file loads but the images and link do not work.  Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?  I'm referencing my img file as img src="$#%.png".

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone" 
        ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];      
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
        bundleURL]];    
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];  
}
```

Comment: try this [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

Comment: Added in answer Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to load `html` file in `UIWebView` :

```
 [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```